# Changing size of dropdown in unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, dropdown

I am having troubles with setting up larger size of dropdown...

as you can see the standard size of dropdown is 160 x 30
so when you click on the dropdown arrow the 3 options below (A B and C) are same size as above and all have same font size ...

But I need to use Larger size of dropdown,  so when I increase the size of it to 320 x 60, and change the font size to 5O...
the change does not affect the 3 options below , A B C  still have  original size of 160 x 30 and original font size which is now way too small ...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY0jZ.jpg]

how do I change this please thanks ... I tried everything

I also noticed that some setting for those 3 dropped downs options don't appear in inspector till you hit play

Thanks in advance

Beri

Answer (score 4):

Given the default `GameObject -> UI-> Dropdown` hierarchy, here is an example for changing the size of the dropdown options:

> [image: example-dropdown]
>
> - Dropdown > Template > Viewport > Content : Height 50
> - Dropdown > Template > Viewport > Content > Item : Height 50,
> - Dropdown > Template > Viewport > Content > Item > Item Label : Font size 24, bold, italic, Vertical Overflow
>
> Source: [Unity forums post by Zaflis](https://forum.unity.com/threads/changing-size-of-dropdown-in-unity.412977/#post-2692088)

Answer (score 1):

When trying to replicate the issue, I found that if you just use the scale tool in the Scene Window on the dropdown, the issue is fixed, so that's what I would do; use the scale tool while looking at `Dropdown` in the inspector for accuracy.

Comment: So, you are saying to scale the entire dropdown object and do not change the font size from the original default setting?

Comment: You could perhaps change some of the template settings to accomplish what this question was asking, but I found this solution to be the quick and easiest way.